# Do children accumulate karma? At what age are you responsible for your karma?

Tags: karma, rebirth, sin, children

If I do a bad karma without knowing or realizing properly will I receive fruits for that or not?

What about children? Do they accumulate karma too? Don't they make lot of mistakes unknowingly?

At what age are you responsible for your own karma?

Comment: All your questions are already on this site. Q1) [Why do bad things happen to good people?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9563/3500) and [If karma works, why are so many evil or corrupted people successful?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8848/3500) Q2) That's because of Karma. One must face Prarabda Karma and Lord **may** mitigate it to some extent. See [Is our destiny predetermined? If yes, then why do our actions affect our karma?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2399/3500) Q3) Christianity is offtopic but all Religions are relatively true if we interpret them Properly.

Comment: Q4) What you sow is what you reap. Karma can be both good and bad. If you repent sincerely, you can wash your sin or bad karma. This is why people **should** take dip in tirthas with **sincere devotion and faith**. Q5) [A question about blood sacrificial acts in Hinduism](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15698/3500), [Is the ritual of killing an animal as offering to Maa Kali correct?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15640/3500) and [Should a Brahmin be vegetarian?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8206/3500)

Comment: I deleted the parts that were duplicative, and now I'm reopening your question.

Answer (score 6):

Children become responsible for their karma after four years of age.

> Boys of less than four years in age can never be guilty or sinful.
>   Even the king cannot punish them.

[Garuda Purana, Dharma Khanda, chapter XLIII]

Comment: Srimad Bhagavatham,Volume 3,chapter 5, stanza 20 - reference to Mandavya rishi who set the limit at 14 years

Comment: Only boys or girls too included?

Comment: I would think that girls are also included.

Answer (score 5):

> If I do a bad karma without knowing or realizing properly will I
>   receive fruits for that or not?

Yes you will.Crimes committed intentionally yields more bad karma without doubt but even those done unknowingly yields bad karma.

For example:

> Manu Smriti 11.145. **The guilt incurred intentionally or
>   unintentionally by injuring (created beings) can be removed by means
>   of these penances;** hear (now, how) all (sins) committed by partaking
>   of forbidden food (or drink, can be expiated).
>
> 11.146. He who drinks unintentionally (the spirituous liquor, called) Varuni, becomes pure by being initiated (again); (even for drinking
>   it) intentionally (a penance) destructive to life must not be imposed;
>   that is a settled rule.

These verses prove that one has to suffer even for one's those sins which were committed unknowingly.

Some further examples:

> A washerman, a cobbler, an actor, a Varuda, a Kaivarta, a Mada, and a
>   Bhilla these seven are known, in the Smriti, as degraded castes. (195)
>   By knowing their women, taking their food and accepting gifts from
>   them, **if willingly, one should perform Prajapatya for a year ; and, if
>   unknowingly, two Chandrayanas. (196**)(Atri Smriti)
>
> ....by **[unconsciously] killing a dog**, one should zealously drink milk
>   for three nights. (7) Or **by [unknowingly] killing a cat or a mongose**,
>   one should wend a way a Yojan [in length](Usana Smriti)

Now,coming to your second question-

**At what age are you responsible for your own karma?**

> **As long as a boy does not attain to the age of eight, [he is known] as
>   a new-born babe**. He is to be known as an embryo, the difference [only]
>   being that of his individuality. (4) '**In the period** [that is during
>   the period] that he is not invested with the sacred thread, **there is
>   no sin in a food and an interdicted edible, in drink, in what should
>   be spoken or not, and in falsehood. (5)**

This is as per **Daksha Smriti(Chapter 1).**

As per Yama Smriti, however,the age limit is 5 years.Its only after that one becomes responsible for Karma.

> A father, brother, or any other relation should perform the penance
>   for a child whose age is below the eleventh year and **above the fifth**.
>   (15) **There is no offence or sin for a child younger than this. There
>   is no punishment from the king for him, nor any penance.** (16)-**(Yama Smriti Chapter 1)**

Comment: arbitrary numbers .. it's surprising none of them say 'once the kid understands what is wrong and what is right...'

Comment: @sv Even that will be  vague..i guess u'r assuming that there is no sin if done unknowingly or if done without knowing that it's a sin..In any case upto certain age (16 i think) they will commit only half sins(at least half penances are prescribed for them) and similarly after certain age(over 80 years ) less penance prescribed..

Comment: @sv *"arbitrary numbers"* - just as arbitrary as the 18-years minor/major classification for juveline/adult crimes ? it's surprising the courts don't say 'once the kid understands what is right and what is wrong'.

Comment: @ram these contradictions happen a lot in Hinduism yet the reason is never given for setting a specific age limit. "it's surprising the courts don't say 'once the kid understands what is right and what is wrong'." They do after the age of 18.

Comment: @rickross what do you think is the reason scriptures contradict each other on the age?

Comment: @Wikash_, nonsense. after 18 you're tried as an adult unless you're insane. it doesn't matter if they understand what's right and wrong or not.

Comment: @ram What do you mean?

Comment: @Wikash_, "They do after the age of 18" - how do you know that they do ? You're just assuming it. And that's what Shastras do as well. They assume that you know after a certain age. Hence, no contradiction.

Comment: @ram most justice systems put the limit at 18. I did not assume that. I am suprised that the scriptures are contradicting and do not give a clear explanation for the choice of age.

Comment: @Wikash_, the explanation is already given - it is assumed that they know, or are taught morals, by the age of 14. "most justice systems" - why most ? why not all ? why is there contradiction among justice systems. let's get rid of superstitious justice system.

Comment: @ram that explanation is not given in the scriptures. Please explain why the iswar would give contradicting numbers. That does not make any sense.

Comment: @Wikash_, there are no contradicting numbers. there are different numbers for different yugas because people's spirituality degrades over time.

Answer (score 1):

If you travel faster than speed limit of road in a new area, will police punish you or not ?
99% of time, ignorance of law is not an excuse, so you will have to bear consequences.. but in rare cases, it might be pardoned

children do not get karma until age 14  - http://www.speakingtree.in/blog/the-story-of-mandavya-rishi

Mandavya rishi tortured an ant when he was a kid. In later life, while he was meditating, a king impaled him on a stick. Mandavya rishi then enquired Yama dharma raja what was the reason for his punishment. Yama said it was due to that crime you committed when you were a child. Mandavya then cursed Yama to be born on earth since children do not know right vs wrong, and also 'rewrote' age of sin to begin from 14 years.

Until then, whatever good/bad they commit, the karma belong to parents. That's why it is very important for us to teach children morals.. not just math & science.

Comment: "Until then...the karma **belongs to parents**" -- please cite sources for this statement. Also, better to cite [Srimad Bhagavatham](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/3/5/20) directly instead of a blog post.

Comment: @SayNoToCensorship If the parents are watching the child do sinful activities and encourage it or allow it, then yes, they do own the karma, the child is like a tool here. If the young child does nonsense without their knowledge, under someone else's supervision or all alone, then yes, I would also like to see a source.

Answer (score 1):

#### As per the Mahābhārata , after the age of 14, one is responsible for their actions and accumulate their fruits accordingly.

A person doesn't accumulate any fruits of their karma up-until 14 years of their chronological age.

This limit has been set by Mahaṛṣi Māṇḍavya after the famous incident involving the Ṛṣi and the god of death - Yamarāja, which has been discussed in [this QnA](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/45127/mandavya-rishi-the-king-and-yamaraja-curse).

[Section 108](https://archive.org/details/TheMahabharataMNDutt/page/n159/mode/1up?view=theater), Sambhava Parva, Book 1 - Ādi Parva, Mahābhārata

> अणीमाण्डव्य उवाच ।
>
> > Aṇīmāṇḍavya said:-
>
> मर्यादां स्थापयाम्यद्य लोके धर्मफलोदयाम् । 
> आ चतुर्दशमाद्वर्षान्न भविष्यति पातकम् ॥
> परेण कुर्वतामेवं दोष एव भविष्यति ॥
>
> > 13. **"I establish this rule to-day on earth in respect of the consequences of one’s act that no sin will be committed in any act done by a man below the age of fourteen years. When committed above the age of fourteen, only then it will be considered as a sin."**
>
> English Translation by M.N. Dutt

Comment: It's only talking about sins and not about all type of karmas isn't it?

Comment: Well, sinful karma won't attach, but, maybe unknowingly done pious karmas will be effective perhaps. That's my conjecture. @LSSJBroly