# When was Yama Smriti lost?

Tags: history, smriti

Yama Smriti is one of the eighteen Smriti which is no more extant.

Till when it is in existence and when did (in which year) we lose that scripture?

Comment: What is extant?

Comment: @Wikash_ Extant means "avaible" or "in circulation" in this context.

Comment: Questions like this one should not be asked on this HiSE website because such questions are highly speculative for nobody really knows the answer to them. You better rephrase the question and ask what was to our knowledge the last time that we know some author mention that Smrti scripture has its manuscripts in existence. This could pass as a valid question appropriate for this website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure why you thought that Yama Smriti is not extant at present. It exists and I have a copy of it and I use it in answers I guess :).

[Here is a PDF](https://www.astrojyoti.com/pdfs/DevanagariFiles/18Yama_Smriti.pdf) of Yama Smriti in Sanskrit only.

It ends thus (from p-7 of the PDF):

> iti yama proktam dharmashastram samaptam (thus ends the Dharma Shastra
> composed by Yama).

I guess we can find English translation of the text on some sites like Archive.org.

Comment: Oh...  Maybe the wrong idea got from websites that it was no more extant...

Comment: [Here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16796) is one answer where I'm quoting from Yama Smriti @hanugm