# What actually is 'Yajna'?

Tags: yajna

What Yajna is?

Today again i came across it in Kularnava tantra, Lord Shiva talking about Mantra Jap being superior to all Yajnas.

So, please tell what yajna is.

Comment: Does this answer your qn ? https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/204/19211

Comment: @Sethu no but still thanks. That was also good answer. Btw i am not asking about yajna related to fire sacrifice but about all. About its literal and basic meaning also.